# Is it possible to get a unique id and order number of current tab in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

All:

I wonder if there are APIs in Chrome can return unique ID and the order number of current active tab,  say if I open Chrome, the first tab open by default will give 0 or something like that as order number and give a unique ID to indicate this tab, then if I open another tab, the second tab will give 1 vice versa and an ID, but if I drag the second tab and move it to the left to take the first one's place, then when I call those APIs, it will give me 0 to indicate the first place and still keep original ID?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for a plugin?

Comment: if you are creating extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

Comment: @epascarello Not yet, just curious about this now.

Comment: Well the browser has no information on that...

Comment: @zp_x thanks, when I open the console, there is no API like chrome.tabs, could you help?

Comment: @Kuan You have to use it in chrome extension or app. It is not available from webpage's javascript.